# How to insert new line text in popup

Tags: leaflet, popup

I'm using Leaflet Marker Cluster and I need to show five different lines in a popup. But when I write this, they are all in the same line. Can someone help me to be one under another?

```
var a = addressPoints[i];
            var title = a[2];
            var univ = a[3];
            var direct = a[4];
            var city = a[5];
            var state = a[6];
            var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), { title: title } );
            marker.bindPopup("Student: " + title + "University: " + univ + "Direction: " + direct + "City: " + city + "State: " + state);
            markers.addLayer(marker);
        }

    map.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the [Leaflet documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup) states, `Marker.bindPopup()` takes an HTML string as first parameter.

If you want your lines to appear on different lines, you need to add the proper HTML markup. In your case, a [definition list](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#dl) seems the most relevant.

Hence:

```
var list = "<dl><dt>Student</dt>"
           + "<dd>" + title + "</dd>"
           + "<dt>University</dt>"
           + "<dd>" + univ + "</dd>"
           + …

marker.bindPopup(list);
```